# override base php functions

Tags: php, function, overloading, radix

I have made a function simular to the print_r function in php.

Is there a way that you can add to the base functions of php so any sites that are on your server can use your new function.

basically i have made a print r with a header to save the sessions to a file for debugging .

does any one know if this is possible.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the core php.ini directive [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

It's effect is that of automatically adding a `require(yourscript.php)` to every PHP script. Just throw your function in there and it's available to all PHP scripts on the server (that use that php.ini).

Answer (score 0):

you can add your function as a PEAR extension and put it in a local PEAR repository.

[Adding functions to PHP core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385531/adding-functions-to-php-core)