# Default functions - PHP

Tags: php

```
function Hello($d){
    echo $d;
}
```

How can I make the following file, index.php, have the `hello` function without modifying index.php?

```
index.php

    <? hello("D") ?>
```

Comment: You could use mod_rewrite to direct requests for index.php to a separate script (let's call it `dispatcher.php`), which includes both the file that defines `Hello()` and index.php.

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea, I was actually thinking about doing that. Im not sure if thats the best way to go (Still a new PHP coder). Do you know which way is faster? Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define your function in some file (somefile.php) and then add that line to Your php.ini file

```
 auto_prepend_file = "/pat/to/somefile.php"
```

from now on that function will be available in every php script so use with care

alternative solution: create index2.php with your function definition - then after that definition add

```
include 'index.php';
```

but with that solution you must call index2.php instead of index.php - but still you won't have to modify contents of index.php

Comment: Hmmm, is there a way that I don't have to change the php.ini file directly? I want to make my library, very easy for people to use and not have to modify their php.ini

Comment: if I would like to use your library then I simply require it IN my code - what you are asking is a way to include your files WITHOUT ANY changes in someones code - it's impossible :) it must be defined somewhere and always someone will have to do something to make it work

just gave them few options - php.ini (or user.ini on some hostings) maybe .htaccess or simple include in their code

Comment: Ah I see. My Library is specially made for the non-coders to make websites. Im trying not to get anyone confused with `include`. The best I can do is make an installer that edits the php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't want to change the file, so I presume no `include`/`require` etc.

That'll leave you with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/385535/249710

It was already answered so I might as wel link it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

By setting the file in-which the Hello() function defined in the include path. The include path is set from php.ini

Comment: Hmmm, Don't I have to put include("hello.php") in index.php to do that?

Comment: Yes you don't need to include hello.php.